# How do I add Amazon.helpintent in audio player

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, ask-sdk

When I ask help, Alexa help invoke instead not the custom help skill. If the audio player not playing eg. on the launch page I get the custom help invoke, but not in the audio player. How can I override that?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

In Audio Player skill when skill starts to play audio, then there is no internal session management and you can only respond using `AudioPlayer directives` like `Play` `Pause` `Next` and some other directives which you can find In this link [here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Per [the AudioPlayer documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html):

> When sending a Play directive, you normally set the `shouldEndSession` flag in the response object to `true` to end the session.

So once the user has invoked the Play Directive, they are no longer interacting with your skill. The user can effect the playback of content from your skill using the [built-in playback control intents](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#intents), but any other interaction with your skill requires use of the normal invocation phrase - e.g. "Alexa, ask [SkillName] for help"

**What about setting `shouldEndSession` to `false`?**

This has the effect of expecting more user input. While this would allow the user to ask for help (or otherwise interact with you skill) immediately after starting the audio playback, it would also [pause the audio playback](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#play) to listen for this input.

Comment: I know the documentation says "…you normally [end session]", but that's wrong. You *have* to end session to get certified.